# implicit conversion changes signedness int to unsigned long long

Tags: c++, qt, warning

[image: int to unsigned long long]
Как лучше исправить предупреждение "implicit conversion changes signedness int to unsigned long long". В строчках :

```
int i=10001;
...
    double *aX = new double [i];
    double *aCxmp = new double [i];
    double *aCxmp1 = new double [i];
    double *aCxcc = new double [i];
    double *aCxcc1 = new double [i];

    double *at = new double [i];
    double *aCtmp = new double [i];
    double *aCtmp1 = new double [i];
    double *aCtcc = new double [i];
    double *aCtcc1 = new double [i];
...
```

Comment: @Harry unsigned int )))) спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном конкретном случае на него можно плюнуть.

Или написать `unsigned int i = 10001;`

Или выполнить явное преобразование типа

```
new double[static_cast<unsigned long long>(i)];
```

Проблема в том, что компилятор в `new[]` ждет положительное значение, и предупреждает, что в вашем `i` может быть и отрицательное...

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ )))